# Why date in string format isn't comparing correctly in Phalcon?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, phalcon

My date variable is behaving strange! I'm using Phalcon query builder to get some records from database through date range. My query is below:

```
if(isset($filter['start_date']) && $filter['start_date'] != '' && isset($filter['end_date']) && $filter['end_date'] != ''){
    $queryBuilder->where('e.created_at >= :startDate: AND e.created_at <= :endDate:');
    $parameters = array('startDate' => $filter['start_date'], 'endDate' => $filter['end_date']);
}
```

in `$parameters` when i put dates manually like this it works fine BUT when i use variables as in above query it isn't working:

```
$parameters = array('startDate' => "2012-10-11", 'endDate' => "2018-10-10");
```

> var_dump($filter['start_date'] is string(10) "2012-10-11" 
>   and for end date
>   var_dump($filter['end_date'] is string(10) "2018-10-10"

Date Datatypes:

```
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

In database dates are stored in datetime format like below example

`2018-11-24 09:05:18`

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? 
Can you confirm that `$filter['start_date']` and `$filter['end_date']` are defined and not empty, so far I don't see anything wrong with your statement. Perhaps you can provide entire `$queryBuilder` statement?

Answer (score 0):

your date must be string expression `'2012-10-11'` otherwise it may be perceived as a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 0):

$filter['start_date'] 
    $filter['end_date']

should be NOT NULL / STRING and be compatible with DATE FORMAT

It's better if you can sanitize or validate the `$filter` before binding it into query builder

Hope it can help you